# How to have fixtures for certain models and REST for everything else?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember app using an API which has most of the models implemented, but some of them not, and for those I would like to provide fixtures.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://api.com'
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  body: DS.attr(),
  author: DS.attr()
});

// ...

this.store.find('post', 1); // http://api.com/post/1

// ...

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  hashtag: DS.attr(),
  color: DS.attr()
});

App.Tag.FIXTURES = [
  { hashtag: 'foo', color: '#000' },
  { hashtag: 'bar', color: '#fff' }
]

// ...

this.store.find('tag', 1) // searches among fixtures
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If you are using `ember-cli` you can have adapter for specific model. E.g adapters/tag.js which extends DS.FixtureAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make adapters specific to models by doing this:
    App.TagAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

Comment: This is more exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a different model with that particular route?

```
App.TagRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [
            { hashtag: 'foo', color: '#000' },
            { hashtag: 'bar', color: '#fff' }
        ];
    }
});
```

Comment: I need those tags stored because I'm using them elsewhere. Or can I still grab them this way?

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I needed. `App.TagController` gets the `model` automatically assigned to this array, so I can access it that way. Thanks!